# Creating new module ZF3 with ZendSkeletonModule

Tags: php, zend-framework3, zf3

I created a new module through git using [ZendSkeletonModule](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonModule):

```
git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonModule.git Users
```

and did the modifications according the new module name. But, even so it's not working and I'm getting `404 error occurred`.

The module name is `User` and here are the files:

```
/module/Users/config/module.config.php
/module/Users/src/Module.php
/config/application.config.php
/config/modules.config.php
/composer.json
```

**/module/Users/config/module.config.php**

```
<?php
namespace Users;

use Zend\Router\Http\Literal;
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

return [
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'users' => [
                'type'    => Literal::class,
                'options' => [
                    // Change this to something specific to your module
                    'route'    => '/users',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller'    => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => [
                    // You can place additional routes that match under the
                    // route defined above here.
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
    ],    
    'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            'Users' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
];
```

**/module/Users/src/Module.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonModule for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2016 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

namespace Users;

class Module
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
    }
}
```

**/config/application.config.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * If you need an environment-specific system or application configuration,
 * there is an example in the documentation
 * @see https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/advanced-config/#environment-specific-system-configuration
 * @see https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/advanced-config/#environment-specific-application-configuration
 */
return [
    // Retrieve list of modules used in this application.
    'modules' => require __DIR__ . '/modules.config.php',

    // These are various options for the listeners attached to the ModuleManager
    'module_listener_options' => [
        // This should be an array of paths in which modules reside.
        // If a string key is provided, the listener will consider that a module
        // namespace, the value of that key the specific path to that module's
        // Module class.
        'module_paths' => [
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ],

        // An array of paths from which to glob configuration files after
        // modules are loaded. These effectively override configuration
        // provided by modules themselves. Paths may use GLOB_BRACE notation.
        'config_glob_paths' => [
            realpath(__DIR__) . '/autoload/{{,*.}global,{,*.}local}.php',
        ],

        // Whether or not to enable a configuration cache.
        // If enabled, the merged configuration will be cached and used in
        // subsequent requests.
        'config_cache_enabled' => true,

        // The key used to create the configuration cache file name.
        'config_cache_key' => 'application.config.cache',

        // Whether or not to enable a module class map cache.
        // If enabled, creates a module class map cache which will be used
        // by in future requests, to reduce the autoloading process.
        'module_map_cache_enabled' => true,

        // The key used to create the class map cache file name.
        'module_map_cache_key' => 'application.module.cache',

        // The path in which to cache merged configuration.
        'cache_dir' => 'data/cache/',

        // Whether or not to enable modules dependency checking.
        // Enabled by default, prevents usage of modules that depend on other modules
        // that weren't loaded.
        // 'check_dependencies' => true,
    ],

    // Used to create an own service manager. May contain one or more child arrays.
    // 'service_listener_options' => [
    //     [
    //         'service_manager' => $stringServiceManagerName,
    //         'config_key'      => $stringConfigKey,
    //         'interface'       => $stringOptionalInterface,
    //         'method'          => $stringRequiredMethodName,
    //     ],
    // ],

    // Initial configuration with which to seed the ServiceManager.
    // Should be compatible with Zend\ServiceManager\Config.
    // 'service_manager' => [],
];
```

**/config/modules.config.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2016 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

/**
 * List of enabled modules for this application.
 *
 * This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
 */
return [
    'Zend\ServiceManager\Di',
    'Zend\Session',
    'Zend\Mvc\Plugin\Prg',
    'Zend\Mvc\Plugin\Identity',
    'Zend\Mvc\Plugin\FlashMessenger',
    'Zend\Mvc\Plugin\FilePrg',
    'Zend\Mvc\I18n',
    'Zend\Log',
    'Zend\Form',
    'Zend\Db',
    'Zend\Cache',
    'ZendDeveloperTools',
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\Validator',
    'Application',
    'Users',
];
```

**/composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for Zend Framework zend-mvc applications",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "mvc",
        "zf"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": "^5.6 || ^7.0",
        "zendframework/zend-component-installer": "^1.0 || ^0.3 || ^1.0.0-dev@dev",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc": "^3.0.1",
        "zfcampus/zf-development-mode": "^3.0",
        "zendframework/zend-cache": "^2.7.1",
        "zendframework/zend-db": "^2.8.1",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc-form": "^1.0",
        "zendframework/zend-json": "^3.0",
        "zendframework/zend-log": "^2.9",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc-i18n": "^1.0",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc-plugins": "^1.0.1",
        "zendframework/zend-psr7bridge": "^0.2.2",
        "zendframework/zend-session": "^2.7.1",
        "zendframework/zend-servicemanager-di": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Application\\": "module/Application/src/",
            "Users\\": "module/Users/src/"
        }       
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "ApplicationTest\\": "module/Application/test/"
        }
    },
    "extra": [],
    "scripts": {
        "cs-check": "phpcs",
        "cs-fix": "phpcbf",
        "development-disable": "zf-development-mode disable",
        "development-enable": "zf-development-mode enable",
        "development-status": "zf-development-mode status",
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@development-enable"
        ],
        "serve": "php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public/ public/index.php",
        "test": "phpunit"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "^1.1.0",
        "zendframework/zend-test": "^3.0.1"
    }
}
```

**Question Update**

Here is the screenshot of the folders and the content of `/module/Users/src/Controller/IndexController.php`:

[image: "/module/Users/src" and "/module/Users/view" folders]

**/module/Users/src/Controller/IndexController.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonModule for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2016 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

namespace Users\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

**Question update 2 - one more file added**

**liga.vconf**

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName liga.localhost
     DocumentRoot /users/cassiomc/sites/sistemas/liga/public
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     <Directory /users/cassiomc/sites/sistemas/liga/public>
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

**Question Update**

Here is the screenshot of 404 screen that I reach when I try to access the `Users` module through the link `liga.localhost/users`.

[image: 404 screen when try access Users module]

**Problem solved - files added to compare with old ones plus 'index.phtml' file of the new Users module**

**/module/Users/config/module.config.php**

```
<?php
namespace Users;

use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;

return [
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'users' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/users[/:action]',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'view_manager' => [
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => [
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'users/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/users/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ],
        'template_path_stack' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
];
```

**/module/Users/src/Module.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonModule for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2016 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

namespace Users;

class Module
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
    }
}
```

**/config/application.config.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * If you need an environment-specific system or application configuration,
 * there is an example in the documentation
 * @see https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/advanced-config/#environment-specific-system-configuration
 * @see https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/advanced-config/#environment-specific-application-configuration
 */
return [
    // Retrieve list of modules used in this application.
    'modules' => require __DIR__ . '/modules.config.php',

    // These are various options for the listeners attached to the ModuleManager
    'module_listener_options' => [
        // This should be an array of paths in which modules reside.
        // If a string key is provided, the listener will consider that a module
        // namespace, the value of that key the specific path to that module's
        // Module class.
        'module_paths' => [
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ],

        // An array of paths from which to glob configuration files after
        // modules are loaded. These effectively override configuration
        // provided by modules themselves. Paths may use GLOB_BRACE notation.
        'config_glob_paths' => [
            realpath(__DIR__) . '/autoload/{{,*.}global,{,*.}local}.php',
        ],

        // Whether or not to enable a configuration cache.
        // If enabled, the merged configuration will be cached and used in
        // subsequent requests.
        'config_cache_enabled' => false,

        // The key used to create the configuration cache file name.
        'config_cache_key' => 'application.config.cache',

        // Whether or not to enable a module class map cache.
        // If enabled, creates a module class map cache which will be used
        // by in future requests, to reduce the autoloading process.
        'module_map_cache_enabled' => false,

        // The key used to create the class map cache file name.
        'module_map_cache_key' => 'application.module.cache',

        // The path in which to cache merged configuration.
        'cache_dir' => 'data/cache/',

        // Whether or not to enable modules dependency checking.
        // Enabled by default, prevents usage of modules that depend on other modules
        // that weren't loaded.
        // 'check_dependencies' => true,
    ],

    // Used to create an own service manager. May contain one or more child arrays.
    // 'service_listener_options' => [
    //     [
    //         'service_manager' => $stringServiceManagerName,
    //         'config_key'      => $stringConfigKey,
    //         'interface'       => $stringOptionalInterface,
    //         'method'          => $stringRequiredMethodName,
    //     ],
    // ],

    // Initial configuration with which to seed the ServiceManager.
    // Should be compatible with Zend\ServiceManager\Config.
    // 'service_manager' => [],
];
```

**/config/modules.config.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2016 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

/**
 * List of enabled modules for this application.
 *
 * This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
 */
return [
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\Validator',
    'Application',
    'Users'
];
```

**/composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for Zend Framework zend-mvc applications",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "mvc",
        "zf"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": "^5.6 || ^7.0",
        "zendframework/zend-component-installer": "^1.0 || ^0.3 || ^1.0.0-dev@dev",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc": "^3.0.1",
        "zfcampus/zf-development-mode": "^3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Application\\": "module/Application/src/",
            "Users\\": "module/Users/src/"            
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "ApplicationTest\\": "module/Application/test/"
        }
    },
    "extra": [],
    "scripts": {
        "cs-check": "phpcs",
        "cs-fix": "phpcbf",
        "development-disable": "zf-development-mode disable",
        "development-enable": "zf-development-mode enable",
        "development-status": "zf-development-mode status",
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@development-enable"
        ],
        "serve": "php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public/ public/index.php",
        "test": "phpunit"
    }
}
```

**Here is the screenshot of the folders and the content of /module/Users/src/Controller/IndexController.php now the code is working:**

[Directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiKm8.jpg)

**/module/Users/src/Controller/IndexController.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonModule for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2016 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

namespace Users\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

**liga.vconf**

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName liga.localhost
     DocumentRoot /users/cassiomc/sites/sistemas/liga/public
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     <Directory /users/cassiomc/sites/sistemas/liga/public>
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

**/module/Users/view/users/index/index.phtml**

```
<strong>Module:</strong>        ZendSkeletonModule &raquo;
<strong>Controller:</strong>    Skeleton &raquo;
<strong>Action:</strong>        index
```

Comment: Just in case, did you do `$ composer dump-autoload`(to update `/vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` and `/vendor/composer/autoload_static.php`) after adding your module in `composer.json`?

Comment: Hello @l_r, thanks for your coment but yes, I did. I performed $ composer update and after I executed $ composer dump-autoload.

Comment: I tested with your files and everything works fine. What do you have in your `module/Users/src` and `module/Users/view` folders and in your `module/src/Controller/IndexController.php`file?

Comment: Hello @l_r, thanks for your help. I updated the question with the info you requested.

Comment: Did you check the folder names and the consistency between files and folders names vs. controllers class and function names (see below). This is where, usually, the 404 comes from.

Comment: I checked the folder names, even in the file "/module/Users/config/module.config.php" I changed the "Users" to "users" but didn't work.

    'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            'Users' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],

Comment: I just recreated the system by "SkeletonApplication" and "SkeletonModule" using the sequence:

1) git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git liga
2) git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonModule.git Users
3) composer install
4) sudo chown -R _www:staff /users/<my_username>/sites/sistemas/liga/data (because permissions on data cache)
5) I updated the module changing the default Skeleton names
6) I performed the "composer update" and "composer dump auto-load"
7) The access do Users module still results 404 error.

Answer (score 3):

If you installed skeleton application with composer and all default dependencies try the following: Add this in composer.json

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Application\\": "module/Application/src/",
            "NewModule\\": "module/NewModule/src/"
        }
    },
```

and run the following in the command line

```
composer dump-autoload
```

I had the same problems as you, but after doing those steps the module is running.

Here is step by step of creating new module
https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/modules/

Comment: Thanks for the info Ivo, but I already had did that as you can see on the composer.json file which I is added to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Check data/cache folder, I deleted *.php files and my module were found by app

Comment: Thanks Vitaliy, I verified the cache and its behavior considering the new module and noted that it was simply being ignored by Zend. I disabled the cache but even so it wasn't worked. But it helped me to continue to search why Zend was not considering the new added module. I configured the necessary files and the new module is working now :)
I'm pasting the same files again. Looking the '/config/modules.config.php', see that there are not too much extra modules as I had included previously. I really don't know what was causing the fail before but now it's working.

Comment: Thank a lot for the hint! I've spent an hour figuring out why I'm getting 404 without any error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `composer.json`, `/config/modules.config.php`, `/config/application.config.php`, `/module/Users/config/module.config.php`, `/module/Users/src/Module.php` files are correct.

Make sure that Controller and Action names are consistent between `module/Users/config/module.config.php`, `module/Users/src/Controller/IndexController.php` and `module/view/users/` path

**module/Users/src/Controller/IndexController.php**

```
<?php
namespace Users\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

**module/users/index/index.phtml**

```
<strong>Module:</strong>        UserModule &raquo;
<strong>Controller:</strong>    Index &raquo;
<strong>Action:</strong>        index
```

**Other try**

If you did everything just fine, it may be the cache. Try to disable it by turning development mode on using the following command: `composer development-enable`.

It will copy `config/development.config.php.dist` into `config/development.config.php` and will change the cache option in the `module_listener_options` array.

Then launch the php server with `composer serve`. It should be working (I did all the install as you did and it works for me). If it doesn't I don't have any other idea...

Comment: Give a try to the update about cache and development mode I added above.

Comment: Thanks for all the help l_r but after make these procedures the module "Users" still remains unavailable resulting 404 error.
The address that I'm using is http://liga.localhost/users considering that "liga.localhost" is the alias set on the Apache ".conf" virtual host file. If I access http://liga.localhost/application it's ok, returning the Skeleton home screen. I'm updating my anser with the ".conf" file too.

Answer (score 0):

Your Module.php should look like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonModule for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2016 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

namespace Users;

class Module
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }
}
```

Remove the "../" within the return.

Comment: Hello Guido, thanks for your help. Unfortunately after remove the "../" I keep reaching the 404 screen when I type "http://liga.localhost/users". I'm adding the 404 screenshot above. If you have some other suggestion, just let me know.